# Macros to copy and paste in loop

Tags: excel, vba

For many of you this might be simple. I need to copy and paste data from 2 specific columns to a new spread sheet; but the macros need to stop when it reaches the end of data or when a cell is blank.

So far the code looks like this:

```
Workbooks.Add
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Muhanad_Reset_import-TEMPLATE.xlsx]Reset_import-Raw Data'!R1C1"
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Muhanad_Reset_import-TEMPLATE.xlsx]Reset_import-Raw Data'!RC1"
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Muhanad_Reset_import-TEMPLATE.xlsx]Reset_import-Raw Data'!R1C3"
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Muhanad_Reset_import-TEMPLATE.xlsx]Reset_import-Raw Data'!RC3"
Range("A1:B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A2:A101").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select
Windows("Muhanad_Reset_import-TEMPLATE.xlsx").Activate
```

I know the code for copy and paste code does not work for a good result.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean code like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lr      As Long
    Dim i       As Long

    lr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reset_import-Raw Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Workbooks.Add

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lr)
        .Formula = "='[Muhanad_Reset_import-TEMPLATE.xlsx]Reset_import-Raw Data'!$A1"
        .Offset(, 1).Formula = "='[Muhanad_Reset_import-TEMPLATE.xlsx]Reset_import-Raw Data'!$C1"
    End With

    Windows("Muhanad_Reset_import-TEMPLATE.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Yasser, Thanks for responding, Can you let me know what does the last part of the code does "Windows(FileName).Activate

Comment: As for the last line, it is already in your code. It just activates the workbook that has the raw data

Comment: Sub Test()
    Dim lr      As Long
    Dim i       As Long
    
    lr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reset_import-Raw Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Workbooks.Add
    
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lr)
        .Formula = "='[Muhanad_Reset_import-TEMPLATE.xlsx]Reset_import-Raw Data'!$A1"
        .Offset(, 1).Formula = "='[Muhanad_Reset_import-TEMPLATE.xlsx]Reset_import-Raw Data'!$C1"
    End With
End Sub

Comment: When I change the data on the sheet an increase the number of rows still the output is generated only for the first 15 rows and no change in output. The output still pulls the initial data from the time of writing the code.

Comment: Sub Test()
    Dim lr      As Long
    Dim i       As Long
    
    lr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reset_import-Raw Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Workbooks.Add
    
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lr)
        .Formula = "='[Muhanad_Reset_import-TEMPLATE.xlsx]Reset_import-Raw Data'!$A1"
        .Offset(, 1).Formula = "='[Muhanad_Reset_import-TEMPLATE.xlsx]Reset_import-Raw Data'!$C1"
    End With
End Sub

Comment: The code defines the last row of the main workbook then relying on that last row the formulas will be copied down ..